# How do I check for a string element stored in a variable in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, random, duplicates

I have a program that is essentially an examination program for students. The program contains two lists that contain words of the opposite meanings, all in the same positional index. For example hot in list1 and cold in list2 both in index 0.

I have created a function which allows the question to be randomly generated and printed for the user to complete. The answers are checked to ensure that combination the user has given is correct. I am now trying to create a function that ensures that no questions in the program are repeated, and i am struggling.

I attempted to create a function that stores the randomly chosen word pairs in a variable, which is then appended into a list. After each question the function is supposed to check for the variable in the list, and if the variable is present, the variable calls for the function which re-generates a new pair. This continues until the questions are all done and there are no duplicates. The program correctly stores the variables in the list (I checked by printing the list)  but when there is a duplicate, the pair generator function doesn't work, and duplicates in the questions are made.

The code to the function I am trying to create is below, and also for the random pair generator and the list. Any Ideas, I need help on this as soon as possible.

Function A:

```
def randcheck():
    global dcheck4
    dcheck = opposite1[decider]
    dcheck2 = opposite2[decider]
    dcheck3 = opposite1[decider2]
    dcheck4 = opposite2[decider2]
    dchecklist.append(dcheck)
    dchecklist.append(dcheck2)
    dchecklist.append(dcheck3)
    dchecklist.append(dcheck4)
    print(dchecklist)

    while dcheck in dchecklist:
        deciders()    
    while dcheck2 in dchecklist:
        deciders()
    while dcheck3 in dchecklist:
        deciders()
    while dcheck4 in dchecklist:
        deciders()
```

Function B:

```
def deciders():
    global countdown
    countdown = len(opposite1) - 1
    global decider
    decider = random.randint(0,countdown)
    global decider2
    decider2 = random.randint(0,countdown)
```

Note: The deciders function comes before the other function in the prorgam, and the list is bellow:

```
global opposite1
opposite1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "bright", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]
global opposite2
opposite2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "dark", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide clearer information. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating the questions one-by-one, use `random.sample` to choose all the indices at once.  Then you're guaranteed that there are no duplicates, and all this checking is obviated.

For example, `random.sample(range(len(opposite1)), 10)` will give you ten indices.

An alternative, and in my opinion, better solution is to zip the two opposite lists together, and then just choose the required number of pairs. Then you don't have to mess with the indices at all.

EDIT: On re-reading your question, I'm not certain I've understood it.  I take it to mean that you are trying to avoid duplicates in the generated list, and that there are no duplicates in the original lists of opposites.

Here's an example of generating 10 questions:

```
import random

opposite1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "bright", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]
opposite2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "dark", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

questions = random.sample(list(zip(opposite1, opposite2)), 10)
for question in questions:
    print(question)
```

In one run, this printed

```
('hot', 'cold')
('reject', 'accept')
('sad', 'happy')
('succeed', 'fail')
('buy', 'sell')
('dry', 'wet')
('heavy', 'light')
('hard', 'soft')
('weak', 'strong')
('win', 'lose')
```

This code is for python 3.  In python 2, you would use

```
zip(opposite1, opposite2)
```

instead of

```
list(zip(opposite1, opposite2))
```

because in python 2, zip already returns a list.

Comment: Yes thats correct. In the list of opposite words, there are no duplicates, but there are when I begin to generate the pairs, which in turn, causes duplicates in the questions.

Comment: How can I apply random sample to this program?

Comment: there is a typo in the code example, check your brackets

Comment: are you sure? As far as I am aware, the second parameter to `sample` has no default value. That call throws an exception/traceback

Comment: @Pynchia  It's too late; I'm getting cross-eyed.  Thanks again.

Comment: @TimicNdoloka  I added an example of how to use `random.sample`